# I cannot find what is wrong with my code

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot find out why the first button in the div on this code does not work on HTML files.
I have checked many javaScript and HTML validators but none of them work.
on codecademy.com and w3schools.com it works but not on HTML files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   #b1 {
        background-image: url('http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/14600000/egypt-egyptian-history-14635051-430-287.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    div {
        width: 990px;
        padding: 25px;
        border: 2px solid navy;
        margin: 25px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body id="b1">
 <script>
    var b = 0;
    var a = function () {
        var q = "blah"
        document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = q;
    };

    var g = function () {
        location.reload();
    };
    var ab = function () {
        var p = "blah";
        document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = p;
    };
    var aq = function () {
        var an = "blah";
        document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = t;
    };
    var di = function () {
        var pe = "blah";
        document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = pe;
    };
    var e = true;
    var a = function () {
        if (e === true) {
            e = false;
            document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = "Ancient Egypt";
        }
        else {
            e = true;
            document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = "Erik Low\'s";
        }

    }
    setInterval(function () { a(); }, 4000);
</script><center>
    <div style="background:white" id="r">

        <h1>Ancient Egypt</h1>
        <h2>Achievements</h2>
        <hr />
        <button onclick="a();">Pyramids</button><br /><br />
        <button onclick="ab();">The Sphinx</button><br /><br />
        <button onclick="aq();">Writing</button><br /><br />
        <button onclick="v();">Mummification</button><br /><br />
        <button onclick="di();">Valley Of The Kings</button><br /><br />
    </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Please change the case in your question to be normal sentence case, and indent code neatly using spaces, not tabs. BTW, your global code is being run before any elements exist in the page.

Comment: What have you done to diagnose it?  Did you check errors in the debug console?  Did you set a breakpoint and trace through the code?  Did you add `console.log()` statements to your code to track what is happening?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**t variable, v function , semicolon missing in your JS code.**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style> #b1{
    background-image: url('http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/14600000/egypt-egyptian-history-14635051-430-287.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;

    background-size:cover;
    }
    div {
    width: 990px;
    padding: 25px;
    border: 2px solid navy;
    margin: 25px;
    }




    </style>
    </head>
    <body id="b1">
    <script>
    var b = 0;
    var a = function() {
    var q= "blah";
    document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = q; 
    };

    var g = function(){
    location.reload();
    };

    var v=function(){
        alert("function v calling");
    }
    var ab=function(){
        var p = "blah";
        document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = p;
         };
         var aq = function(){
        var an = "blah";  
        var t="writing";
     document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = t;
             };
             var di = function(){
                 var pe = "<h1>Valley Of The Kings</h1><hr/><br/><img src=\"http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-YUOUb6HSFcg/UbjX528O3zI/AAAAAAAAFw4/BXgpfsGvHgw/s1600/t1.jpg\" width=\"700\"><br/><h2>What Is The Valley Of The Kings</h2><p>The Valley Of The Kings is a valley in which many pharaohs were burried.</p><br/><h2>Who Was Burried There</h2><br/><p>In the East Valley Of The Kings Ramesses VII,<br/> Ramesses IV, Ramesses XI, Ramesses IX, Ramesses II,<br/> Merenptah, Ramesses V, Ramesses VI, Amenmesse,<br/> Ramesses III, Ramesse Khamenteru, Amenherkhepshef,<br/> Mentuherkhepshef, Twosret, Setnakhte, Seti II, Ramesses I, Seti I, Ramesses X, Mentuherkhepshef,<br/> Thutmose I, Hatshepsut, Tia\'a, Thutmose III, Amenhotep II, Maiherpri,<br/> Amenhotep I, Hatshepsut-Meryetre, Thutmose IV, Userhet, Yuya,<br/> Tjuyu, Siptah, Amenemopet called Pairy, Akhenaten, Horemheb,<br/> Sitre In, and Tutankhamen were burried.<br/> In the West valley Ay, Akhenaten, and Amenhotep III were burried.</p><br/><br/><p>Sources</p>";
                 document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = pe;
                 };
                 var e=true;
    var a = function() {
    if (e===true){
    e=false;
    document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = "Ancient Egypt";
    }
    else{
    e=true;
    document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = "Erik Low\'s";
    }

    }
    setInterval(function(){ a(); }, 4000);
    </script><center>
    <div style="background:white" id="r">

    <h1>Ancient Egypt</h1>
    <h2>Achievements</h2>
    <hr/>
    <button onclick="a();">Pyramids</button><br/><br/>
    <button onclick="ab();">The Sphinx</button><br/><br/>
    <button onclick="aq();">Writing</button><br/><br/>
    <button onclick="v();">Mummification</button><br/><br/>
    <button onclick="di();">Valley Of The Kings</button><br/><br/>
    </div>
    </center>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Posting poorly formatted code isn't a [*good answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you but i do not understand what you did to make it work

Comment: t variable, v function , semicolon missing in your JS code.

Comment: the answer contains a value for `var pe` in function, `di` that was 'blah' in the question, but some long html in the answer - and incredibly, the answer is correct. @HussyBorad - how **did** you know what pe should've been?

Comment: this answer regarding before they edit this question. In That code he write this things in `pe`, but after questions edit he remove that things. i am not free for i am see every time they what change in their code.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a ;

```
var q= "blah";
```

Also

```
document.getElementById('a')
```

This is null so there is no innerHTML of null.
You have no html tag with id = 'a'

Comment: sorry i had to delete most stuff on my full code but there was